# Recover BMP image header

Tags: linux, image, bmp, recover

I am trying to recover some BMP image header, and the all information I got is this:

- the bytes of the header that have been deleted are 54
- the start offset is 1130 (decimal)
- the width is 350 (decimal).
- bits per pixel is 8
- no compression

So I read little bit (mostly from [here](http://www.file-recovery.com/bmp-signature-format.htm)) and I saw which bytes present what, and I got the next first 54 bytes of the BMP header:

```
42 4D 6E 7F 0C 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 F4 01 00 00 22 02 00 00 01 00 18 00 00 00 00 00 38 7F 0C 00 13 0B 00 00 13 0B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

But for some reason, when I am trying to open my all BMP images and my header, I get just a black image. Did I do something wrong? Do I build the 
wrong header from the information above?

Comment: Sorry, I find your question impossible to understand. Please state clearly what you have, what is missing, what you are trying to do and what you have tried so far. Thank you.

Comment: Is the file size 819054 B ( 0x0C7F6E) or you need to add/subtract 54 to that?

Comment: 54 bytes from the start is missing. i need to recover the heder by the information above, how can i do that?

Comment: If you got all numbers correct, this should work. (*If*.) Share your original file so we can check.